# Activities on Opportunities

Tags: custom-report-type

I am trying to pull the report for activities on Opportunities.  I have created a CRT "Opportunities with Activities" and deployed it.  When I am trying to pull the report for all opportunities for all time, it is not showing up any result.  Any idea what may be the reason.  Is there any other way I can pull my report on opportunity activities.  Thanks

Comment: Which date field did you use for the 'all time' filter?  For example : Opportunity.createddate would be ideal

Answer (score 2):

The report type "Opportunities with Activities" will quite literally only return Opportunities that **have** activities.

Any Opportunities that don't have an Activity will not appear in this report. In your report type, change the option to ensure you have set **"A" records may or may not have related "B" records.**